# Spring not resolving JSP and JSON with the same URL prefix

Tags: java, jsp, rest, spring-mvc

**My goal:**

1. `http://host:port/myApp/about` returns a jsp page called `about.jsp`
2. `http://host:port/myApp/about/log` is a service call that returns JSON

**My web.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" ...>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            ...
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**My servlet.xml (using Spring 3.0.3.RELEASE):**

```xml
<beans ...>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan ... />

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="15728640" /> <!-- 15 MB -->
    <property name="MaxInMemorySize" value="15728640" /> <!-- 15 MB -->
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

**My controller:**

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("about")
public class AboutController {

    @RequestMapping(method=GET)
    public String getStats() {
        return "about";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="log", method=GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<String> getLog() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**On server (jetty 6, servlet-api 2.5) startup I see:**

```
INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/about/log] onto handler [AboutController@63843ca4]
INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/about/log.*] onto handler [AboutController@63843ca4]
INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/about/log/] onto handler [AboutController@63843ca4]
INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/about] onto handler [AboutController@63843ca4]
INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/about.*] onto handler [AboutController@63843ca4]
INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/about/] onto handler [AboutController@63843ca4]
```

**Results from that setup for the goals listed above:**

1. Produces the error:

   ```
   WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myApp/WEB-INF/views/about.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myApp'
   ```
2. Works as expected

**Things I've checked/tried:**

- `WEB-INF/views/about.jsp` does exist
- I have put breakpoints in my controller for both methods and they are both being called appropriately; the breakdown happens sometime after exiting my controller class
- The order of `InternalResourceViewResolver` is purposely set to be first. I know [the Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver-chaining) recommend against this, but when I tried putting it last I get an empty `{ }` returned which I assume is because `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` picks up the "about" string and interprets it somehow. I have no requirements for the order, but the settings in `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` need to stay the way they are (unless it is absolutely necessary for them to change).
- Set the url-pattern in web.xml to `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`, but that breaks references to static resources (which is not an option since those resources are currently being used by many 3rd-parties in production)
- Set the url-pattern in web.xml to `<url-pattern>/about/*</url-pattern>`, but then I get opposite results as listed above:

  1. Works as expected
  2. Produces the error:

     ```
     WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myApp/about/log.json] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myApp'
     ```

  Interestingly, the url `http://host:port/myApp/about/about/log` *does* work with this url-pattern

So, I'm a bit stuck on what to fix to achieve the stated goals.

Comment: Speculating :-) - Is it a unix box by any chance, may be the process running tomcat does not have access to about.jsp file?

Comment: @BijuKunjummen: I'm testing this on a Mac, but I would hope that is not making a difference. I don't think it is since I can find `about.jsp` just fine in the scenario I described when I changed the url-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific need for u to use InternalResourceViewResolver?

To configure jackson plugin we only need

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

try with this XML

```
<beans ...>
 <context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan ... />

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="15728640" /> <!-- 15 MB -->
    <property name="MaxInMemorySize" value="15728640" /> <!-- 15 MB -->
</bean>


<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I tried using `UrlBasedViewResolver` (with `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView` as the view class), but unfortunately it produces the same results. I would expect this since `InternalResourceViewResolver` is just a subclass of `UrlBasedViewResolver` [according to the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-view-resolvers-tbl).

Comment: You should not get this error..No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myApp/WEB-INF/views/about.jsp] ..everything seems to be correct..what is the need of InternalResourceViewResolver? Pardon me but as per ur requirement I cant see any specific need for going with InternalResourceViewResolver..I hope you are deploying the war properly..any other error ur getting in server log?